# API in Django but based on protobuf

Tags: python, django, api, serialization, protocol-buffers

I need to create an API in Django but unfortunately communication must be based on protobuf.

What worries me most are quite complicated data models. If I'm not mistaken definitions in models.py must be duplicated in .proto files and handling requests will require lots of 'conversions' between Django ORM and proto messages. Developing and maintaining can be very uncomfortable - minor models edits will require to edit .proto and requests.

So I dream of some framework which will do the magic in background by itself. It could give excessive set of methods, but its biggest advantage would be automation f.e. creating .proto definitions based on models.py

Unluckily three days of searching for a solution have not given expected results. So I need to prepare an 'emergency' plan.

At first I thought about django-piston and its emitters but the project is abandoned. So maybe Tastypie and its serialization? But I'm not sure if I can handle it for protobuf by my own. I'll make some experiments with cprotobuf package, but any hints and solution will be much appreciated.

Are Tastypie and cprotobuf the easiest solution or maybe there are some helpers which will save me effort and nerves?

Comment: it would be helpful to provide a sample of models.py and the .proto file you would like to be at the end.

Comment: It doesn't matter. My idea was: let's define models.py and the tool will generate appropriate .proto files and methods for manipulating the model through an API. Something like Django REST Framework, but based on protobuf. Unfortunately probably there is no such tool...

Comment: @Rympau I had the same idea. How is your protobuf based project doing (nearly two years later)?

Comment: In my experience with both, Django Rest Framework is a lot more consistent with Django. Serializers are similar to forms, and the generic views are pretty similar. As a result I found that far easier to use.

Comment: @wobbily_col any solution for using proto_buf with it ?

Comment: not sure if it's useful but... https://github.com/myyang/django-pb-model